# IOS TESSERACT: Disable Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, tesseract

Is there a way to disable word finding in iOS Tesseract?

Particularly for swift if there is a way

```
        let tesseract = G8Tesseract()
        tesseract.language = "eng"
        tesseract.engineMode = .TesseractCubeCombined
        tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = .SingleChar
        tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 60.0
        tesseract.image = pickedImage.g8_grayScale()
        tesseract.recognize()
        let text = tesseract.recognizedText
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `tessedit_enable_doc_dict` to 0.

You can do that in G8Tesseract with the following method:

```
- (void)setVariableValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

where the value is "0" and the key "tessedit_enable_doc_dict".

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out.